# Python view of data sending over ethernet using socket

Tags: python

my question is about sending data via Ethernet using Python and Socket. 
I've just created a socket on Python side, I think the code is just simple and understandable. In this way I'd like just send data outside the computer.

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 'tcp')
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345  # Example of a port
s.connect((host, port))  # set server connection((ip_server, port_server))
s.send("Data to send")
print s.recv(1024)  # receive data form the socket; argument is a bufsize
s.close
```

And if I create the socket right above, then the send data go via the port outside? Is it enough to for data to go out via the port? Using some sniffer programs I should see the data in some way?

Comment: Yeah , the first tow question answer is yes , and if you want more security on your connection see [ssl](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
I have such a problem:

return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] and the comment is : can't set the connection because the destination computer refuses it